# Detect application language instead of phone language

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have multi language application and I want to display date in English if the selected language on phone is not supported by the application translations.

**Is there any method to get language used by application (default English)
instead of language selected in the phone?**

Looks like this is returning only the phone language:

```
Locale.getDefault()
getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check whether the system language is not available in your translations?

Comment: It would be but how ? @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: 1. Get system language; 2. Put available translation languages in list; 3. Check if system language is in that list.

Comment: Yes but this "2. Put available translation languages in list" is a bit problematic. @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with "_language used by application (default English) instead of language selected in the phone_"

Comment: For example user from Arabia has selected Arabic language which is not supported by application. And then application using English language displaying date in Arabic because of Locale.getDefault()

Comment: @Esperanz0 I have done the same things. can you tell me a little bit more so that I can help you?
are you taking date from `DatePickerDialog` or formatting it?

Comment: Android uses the default localization if the user's selected device locale is not included in the resources. Isn't that exactly what you're looking for? In which language is  your default localization now?

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati Yes something like that.

Comment: @Torben And the language of application is fine. But date is formated by Locale.getDefault() which is not default English language and date is formated by language selected in phone.

Comment: **String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();**

Comment: @Harshilkakadiya For some reasons it's returning language selected on phone instead of app.

Comment: hey @Esperanz0. I have just posted my answer check it and let me know if you want any further explanation or change.

Answer (score 0):

Get system language

```
Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
```

Get application language

```
String appLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

Comment: It also returning system language not the app language.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

I have made one extension function to format date with the default locale of the app or only English.

**Note: This function will always return formatted date in English it doesn't matter what your device language or whats your app language.**

**And if you want to date as per your app language just pass your app's selected language locale to this method.**

Before showing `DatePickerDialog` set `Locale` to `en` like this.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale("en"))
startDatePickerDialog.show()
```

And after that use this method to format date.

```
 fun Context.getFormattedDate(
    inputFormat: String = "dd/MM/yyyy",
    outputFormat: String,
    inputDate: String,
    locale: Locale = Locale("en")
): String {

    val inputFormat = inputFormat
    var outputFormat = outputFormat

    var parsed: Date? = null
    var outputDate = ""

    val dfInput = SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, locale)
    val dfOutput = SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, locale)

    try {
        parsed = dfInput.parse(inputDate)
        outputDate = dfOutput.format(parsed)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("formattedDateFromString", "Exception in formate Date From string(): " + e.message)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return outputDate

}
```

How to use this function

```
 Log.e("Formated date", getFormattedDate(
                    inputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy",
                    outputFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy",
                    inputDate = "17/05/2019"
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no helpfull answer I will post my solution for this problem.

So I decided to create xml file for every supported language with locale code inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="language_locale">en</string>
</resources>
```

Example usage:

```
fun Date.formatWithShortMonthAndDay(context: Context, date: Date): String {
    val locale = context.resources.getString(R.string.language_locale)
    return SimpleDateFormat(DATE_WITH_SHORT_MONTH_AND_DAY_PATTERN, Locale(locale)).format(date)
}
```